# How to put a .tar file inside a .tar.gz file using Java?

Tags: java, tar

Im looking to create a .tar.gz that contains sub directories that are .tar files.

I have two seperate things working right now, I am able to create a data.tar file with the needed information inside. I also have a .tar.gz working, but the subdirectories are not .tar files, for example:
data.tar (Working)
|-directory/
|--files

file.tar.gz (Working)
|-data/
|--directory/
|---files

Goal:
file.tar.gz (Not Working)
|-data.tar
|--directory/
|---files

To add a .tar to my .tar.gz i am doing the following creating a .tar file and then adding that .tar file to my .tar.gz

```java
public class TarArchiveOutput extends Closeable {

    public BufferedOutputStream       bOut;
    public GzipCompressorOutputStream gzOut;
    public TarArchiveOutputStream     tOut;
    private boolean isZipped;

    public TarArchiveOutput(OutputStream oStream, boolean zip) throws IOException {
        bOut  = null;
        gzOut = null;
        tOut  = null;
        isZipped = zip;
        if(isZipped) {
            bOut = new BufferedOutputStream(oStream, 1024 * 10240);
            gzOut = new GzipCompressorOutputStream(bOut);
            tOut = new TarArchiveOutputStream(gzOut);
            tOut.setLongFileMode(TarArchiveOutputStream.LONGFILE_POSIX);
        } else {
            bOut = new BufferedOutputStream(oStream, 1024 * 10240);
            tOut = new TarArchiveOutputStream(bOut);    
            tOut.setLongFileMode(TarArchiveOutputStream.LONGFILE_POSIX);
        }
    }

    public void addFileToOutput(String path, String base) throws IOException {
        File f = new File(path);
        if(!base.endsWith("/"))
            base = base+"/";
        String entryName = base + f.getName();
        TarArchiveEntry tarEntry = new TarArchiveEntry(f, entryName);
        tOut.putArchiveEntry(tarEntry);

        if (f.isFile()) {
            IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(f), tOut);
            tOut.closeArchiveEntry();
        } else {
            tOut.closeArchiveEntry();
            File[] children = f.listFiles();
            if (children != null) {
                for (File child : children) {
                    addFileToOutput(child.getAbsolutePath(), entryName + "/");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        if(isZipped) gzOut.close();
        tOut.close();
        bOut.close();
    }
}
```

To create just a .tar file:

```java
TarArchiveOutput dataTarOutput = new TarArchiveOutput(new FileOutputStream(new File("data.tar")), false);
//Add files
```

Creating .tar.gz

```java
TarArchiveOutput tarGZOutput = new TarArchiveOutput(new FileOutputStream(new File("file.tar.gz")), true);
tarGZOutput.addFileToOutput("data.tar", "");
```

I expect the format to be as follows:
file.tar.gz
|-data.tar
|--directory/
|---files

The actual result is a .tar.gz that when uncompressed/untar it contains a data.tar file but when i try to untar that it turns into a data.tar.cpgz (infinite loop), can not uncompress. Thanks in advance any help would be great!

Comment: A `tar.gz` archive is actually a `tar` archive that has been compressed with Gzip.

Comment: @devgianlu i also tried adding a .tar to a .tar by passing both to false and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

In order to GZip the TAR archive you need to do the following:

```
TarArchiveOutput dataTarGzOutput = new TarArchiveOutput(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("data.tar.gz"))), false);
```